# Is it possible for an ssh server to know which public domain name was used to log into it?

Tags: linux, ssh, dns, openssh, sshd

I have a situation where I need to set up an ssh server which will be accessible by multiple different public domain names, but will provide a different TTY interface to the user depending on the domain name they used.

I want to know if the following requirement is *possible* before I try to implement it, and if so, how:

I have two domain names that provide two different kinds of BBS-style service via ssh. In actuality, both domain names route to the same physical Linux box, but the Linux box needs to resolve which domain was used to access it, in order to give the user the illusion that they are two independent services.

Example:

When a user logs in via their username, I want to set up my ssh server to determine whether the user connected to example.com or example.org. If they connected to user@example.com, they will get a bash shell, and if they connected to user@example.**org**, they should get a TTY-based MUD game instead.

How might I go about getting this info from sshd? Does sshd set an environment variable? Or, am I on the wrong track? Is there an easier approach for running multiple ssh services off one server?

Comment: See also [Do the SSH or FTP protocols tell the server to which domain I am trying to connect?](https://serverfault.com/q/672270/168875#672403)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The SSHv2 protocol (unlike e.g. HTTP or TLS) doesn't have a standard way for clients to provide this information to the server. The server can only see TCP socket information (which OpenSSH exposes in $SSH_CONNECTION).

You can try discussing a new protocol extension on e.g. the OpenSSH mailing list (the logical way to implement it would be via the recently-added key exchange extension mechanism), but even if it is written and accepted, it will take a long time until the majority of clients support such hostname indications.

Practically, you will need to obtain a 2nd IP address for your MUD domain, or run the game on an alternate TCP port, or set up a special username that tells one service to bridge into the other.